# Enabling IntelliSense in Visual Studio 2013 Express for C++ files with irregular extensions (e.g. .tpp)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am implementing a class template in Visual Studio 2013 Express with a header and implementation file. However, my implementation file (which has a .tpp extension) does not have IntelliSense enabled. Is there any way to enable C++ IntelliSense for this file?

Comment: I don't get the point of these exotic extensions. Why not name it a .h file?

Comment: Tools->Options->Text Editor->File Extensions . At least for syntax-highlighting, for compilation considerations, add them to the xml of the project or right click them and select and in the properties select the Item Type C/C++ Compiler

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Tools->Options->Text Editor->File Extensions`. At least for syntax-highlighting, for compilation considerations, add them to the xml of the project or right click them and select and in the properties select the Item Type C/C++ Compiler.

[PeterT Nov 9 '14 at 22:45](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26833905/enabling-intellisense-in-visual-studio-2013-express-for-c-files-with-irregular#comment42234599_26833905)

Comment: Just if you're confused that nothing happens - I needed to restart VS, then everything worked :)